# How can I get split one serial connection into two

Tags: linux, debian, serial

I need to get an application and a monitor to read from the same serial port, the application will be the only program that will be able to read/write  to the serial port and the monitor will only be able to read.

I hope to achieve this:

```
                                      /----->(Application)
---(/dev/ttyUSB0 Serial connection)---
                                      \----->(Monitor)
```

I hear socat, might be able to do this. But I am unsure on how to do this.

How exactly can I do this? Its a serial connection running at 192K baudrate and I am running it on a Debian Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

There is small utility called `tee` that split `stdin` into `stdout` and arbitrary file(s), possibly pipes, that can be red by two or more different applications.

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tee somefile1.txt somefile2.txt | application &
tail -F somefile1.txt | monitor &
tail -F somefile2.txt | parser &
```